# react useEffect with function received as props from parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, use-effect

I have a parent component

```
import React ,{useState} from 'react'

import ChildComponenet from './child'

export default function App() {
  const [parentValue , setParentValue] = useState(0)


  const someParentfunc = (input1,input2)=>{
    setParentValue( parseInt(input1,10) +parseInt(input2,10))
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      Add : {parentValue}
      <ChildComponenet someParentfunc={someParentfunc} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

now the child component :

```
import React ,{useState,useEffect} from 'react'


function ChildComponenet({someParentfunc}) {
  const [input1 , setInput1] = useState(10)
  const [input2 , setInput2] = useState(20)
  
  useEffect(() => {
    someParentfunc(input1,input2)
  }, [input1,input2])

  return (
        <div>
          <input type="text"
            value={input1}
            onChange={event => setInput1(event.target.value) }
          />
        <input type="text"
            value={input2}
            onChange={event => setInput2(event.target.value) }
          />
       </div>
  )
}

export default ChildComponenet
```

the error is: **React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'someParentfunc'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.**

should I add **someParentfunc** in the **useEffect** , will it be right approach :

```
useEffect(() => {
    someParentfunc(input1, input2);
  }, [input1, input2,someParentfunc]);
```

the working project link is : https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-kare-kce02?file=/src/child.js

Comment: What did you find when you googled?

Comment: Yes, it is the right approach - you shouldn't omit any dependency from the dependency array of the `useEffect` hook. Wrap `someParentfunc` in `useCallback` hook and then in the child component, add it in the dependency array of the `useEffect` hook

Comment: https://medium.com/@infinitypaul/reactjs-useeffect-usecallback-simplified-91e69fb0e7a3   
This article elaborates @Yousaf suggestion. Its a better practice to wrap it in a useCallback.

Answer (score 0):

`someParentfunc` is not using any value from it closures and so if you avoid it in in the dependency, there shouldn't be any problem. However for the purpose of ou code being extendable you should try to follow the patterns and add it in the dependenccy so that if doesn't cause any issues if the function is updated in future

To add it as a dependency you should make sure to use `useCallback` function so that the function is not re-created on each re-render

```
export default function App() {
  const [parentValue , setParentValue] = useState(0)


  const someParentfunc = useCallback((input1,input2)=>{
    setParentValue( parseInt(input1,10) +parseInt(input2,10))
  }, [setParentValue]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      Add : {parentValue}
      <ChildComponenet someParentfunc={someParentfunc} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now you can add it to the useEffect dependenccy in child component

```
function ChildComponent({someParentfunc}) {
  const [input1 , setInput1] = useState(10)
  const [input2 , setInput2] = useState(20)
  
  useEffect(() => {
    someParentfunc(input1,input2)
  }, [input1,input2, someParentfunc])

  return (
        <div>
          <input type="text"
            value={input1}
            onChange={event => setInput1(event.target.value) }
          />
        <input type="text"
            value={input2}
            onChange={event => setInput2(event.target.value) }
          />
       </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did not use "useCallback" before, I will try to learn that .